# Tensorflow Object Detection not learning on custom dataset (Monkey Images)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Am trying tensorflow object detection on a custom dataset, for some reason my model is not learning anything
here is a list of what i tried

1. i tried training pet data set from  Oxford-IIIT Pet Dataset as in [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine). It worked as expected
2. Now i followed [this](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9) tutorial to train my own dataset ( for testing am just using images of monkeys)

but unfortunately my model is not learning anything[image: screen-shot of tensorboard]

Info : am training on google could platform as in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine). My configuration pipeline [config](https://gist.github.com/Shivakishore14/b564213f4b59180e9efe1f9faf6fa3da), my [pbtxt](https://gist.github.com/Shivakishore14/d3d834df83f42f4a436011e07c0e2da8).

I created annotations using [Labelimg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg)

**EDIT**

No actual detection is seen even after 6hrs of training in google cloud platform
[image: val]
and no increase in Precision is seen.

**EDIT 2**

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66vuGcF7uMWVGZyVUxMQkd3cUE) to dataset. I have not used all the images in this dataset as some of them were irrelevant, I have used only the images which i have annotated.

Comment: you model is learning properly. Only the learning rate is constant

Comment: @IshantMrinal i have updated my question, what might be the reason for not detecting any monkeys?

Comment: check your `nms_threshold` . not sure exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Would you be willing to share your dataset? It's possible something is formatted incorrectly.

Unrelated, but I also noticed your num_classes argument is set to 37. It can probably be set to 1 for the monkey's dataset.

Comment: @DerekChow I have added the dataset link to the question, Thanks in advance

Comment: how about verify your model by using your training data set?

Comment: @yuhow5566 I have two datasets train dataset and test dataset, its on two different folders as monkey_train and monkey_test in the dataset link given above

Comment: @ShivaKishore Well, what I mean is test your final model by asking it to detect monkeys of those photos in your 'training data set'. Its a self-consistence test. If your model really don't learn anything, it recognizes nothing from your training data set.

Comment: @yuhow5566 I did test with same images from the training dataset, even then my model was not able to recognize anything. so it must not be learning anything right? and if its not learning anything what might be the reason? thanks

Comment: having the same issue

Comment: I have no luck with `rfcn_resnet101` either. It cannot learn anything either.

Comment: I have a similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469300/tensorflow-cannot-detect-anything-in-eval-images-while-training
The num_classes is set to 1 though.

Answer (score 2):

One issue could be that in the config file, the number of classes is `37`, but for your dataset you only have a single class. Try to change the num_classes in the config file to `1` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. I tried with TensorBox and I got some good results with learning. Now I can not do with Tensorflow. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoOMx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my own training dataset.

- Loss was converging to near 0 indicating that the network was learning
- The evaluation set would produce very few or absolutely no detections

My case was a little different from @ShivaKishore in that I had many classes in my dataset. After a few attempts at debugging one eventually produced detections. *I reduced my number of classes to a single class*. This is not to say that you can only identify a single class but rather it rooted out a bug in my tfrecord generation. I'm still trying to figure out what that bug was. I know that I have many labels that are not found in my "debug" version of the dataset, which perhaps causes a problem?

I think that my problem and @ShivaKishore's problem are a bit different but have the same root, the network and the class labels do not jive. @ShivaKishore did you ever fix the num_classes issue that others have pointed out? I'm optimistic that will fix your problem.