# How to improve precision of object detection using tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, object-detection

I am applying tensorflow object detection api to build a model to detect a single object. My own dataset contains 2150 images for training and 540 for test.

All images are of 1920 (width) by 1080 (height). The object in each image is very small, approximately 55 by 15. Also, there are a lot of noise. Here is **an example image of my dataset** that is correctly identified (the majority of images cannot be identified):

[image]

I have tried all of the models in the [detetion_model_zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md), none of them gave me satisfying results. **The mAP is very low after training. the precision is only approximate 0.3**. Here is the evaluation of using `ssd_inception_v2_coco`:

[image]

**Any suggestions on improve the model?** Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following things:

1) Break your images into smaller crops so that the objects of interest end up being a bit bigger.  You can do this just at inference time, or you can do both training and inference with crops.  Don't worry if some of the crops don't contain anything interesting.

2) Use a more powerful model such as faster r-cnn with resnet or inception resnet.

3) Figure out what human performance is to get an idea of what the upper bound on the performance of your machine learning system is likely to be.

Comment: I just tried your first suggestion. I sliced each image into 6 smaller ones, and the model can detect more objects from it at the inference time. It is intuitive for human to detect objects in this way, I thought the machine can identify object anyway as long as it learns the necessary features. Is there any theoretical rationale behind this? Thank you very much! I will let you know the results of your other suggestions!

Comment: I trained a model with `rfcn_resnet101`. Surprisingly, it did not perform well, which means the model cannot 'see' any object in new images. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: `rfcn_resnet101` is not learning anything. I did try evaluation on train dataset, it still cannot detect anything. Looks like it happens to several other people as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546556/tensorflow-object-detection-not-learning-on-custom-dataset-monkey-images?rq=1